# fpsdisplaysink not working in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, gstreamer, frame-rate

I had a video stream sever which is capable of capturing the video frames through camera using rtp.I had my android mobile as the client end and able to stream the output through the following pipeline:

udpsrc port=5004 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse  !  decodebin ! autovideosink

However if i replace **autovideosink** with **fpsdisplysink** to check the framerate,it throws error.

Error:
**Unable to build pipeline:no element "fpsdisplaysink".**

Is there anyother way to display the frame rate?

Here i'll be using gstreamer-1.0 version for streaming.

Comment: Do you have gstreamer plugins bad installed?

Comment: @mpr Thanks for the reply.No i don't have this plugin installed.I came to know that fpsdisplaysink is listed under the gstdebugutilsbad plugin.So i have done cerbero build for this recipe and added the libgstdebugutilsbad.a which i got from build result.Still no improvement.Any suggestions???

Comment: fpsdisplaysink is the only way I know to get framerate without wrapping the pipeline in an application.  I'm not familiar with the Android build system for GStreamer, but if you have plugins-good installed you can't be too far off.

Comment: Which version of GStreamer are you using? I added this plugin more than a year ago to the build and e.g. 1.2.0 includes it already. The relevant commit is this here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/commit/?id=6bcc90e632169deb5e1caa2a5c75d2dba97dcd93

You can get the latest binaries from here: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.4.5/

Don't use anything from gstreamer.com, it's not related to the GStreamer project and the binaries they provide are based on the >2 year old 0.10 release series (which is no longer maintained)

Comment: Thanks mpr to share some ideas on fpsdisplaysink.

Comment: @SebastianDröge I using Gstreamer-1.0 version.Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: @SebastianDrögeI had gone through the link which you shared.I already have the latest libraries(gstreamer-1.0-android-arm-1.5.0.zip.bz2).Inside this library i had found libgstdebugutilsbad.a file and added to my jni folder and the corresponding libgstdebugutilsbad.so too created.But still same error.

Comment: You have to add it to your Android.mk, not copy any files around. Just like all the other plugins.

Comment: @SebastianDrögeThank's sebastian,now i had removed all my external libraries added.I had include all the plugin,still same issue.

Comment: Can you have any idea under which plugin this fpsdisplaysink element will come under?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fpsdisplaysink element is working fine now,as i mis-spelled the PLUGIN name in Android makefile.Instead of GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS we added the name as GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECT.